# The term 'Win32' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet - pass a pipe symbol as part of an argument

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line-interface, quotes, quoting

I'm trying to make script for automate build's.
Stacked on "release|Win32" command

Command:

```
PS C:\Users\Builder> powershell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com'" C:\Build\
VS2012Build\3.2.7X\ClientServer\SHClientServer\SHCApplicationsVS2012.sln /Clean Release|Win32 No Local
```

Error:

```
The term 'Win32' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spell
ing of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:193
+ powershell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com'" C:\Build\VS2012Build\3.2.7X
\ClientServer\SHClientServer\SHCApplicationsVS2012.sln /Clean Release|Win32 <<<<  No Local
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Win32:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `|` is a metacharacter (a character with syntactic meaning) in PowerShell, you must *quote* it if you want to use it as part of an argument - either individually with `` ` `` or, more typically, by (single- or double-)quoting the entire argument:

```
powershell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com' C:\Build\VS2012Build\3.2.7X\ClientServer\SHClientServer\SHCApplicationsVS2012.sln /Clean 'Release|Win32' No Local"
```

- Note how `Release|Win32` is now single-quoted (`'Release|Win32'`).
- Also, I've enclosed the *entire* PowerShell command in `"..."` for robustness.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Vlad; my pleasure.